Как проверить строки с JSON файла C#
Есть такой JSON
 {
  "Game": {
    "Door1": [
      "AH3O-A9BJ-X3SD-WE5O",
      "I9IW-HSCL-90FM-2SJ8",
      "DK06-4TM0-NEA1-TSCE",
      "48NI-CQ03-4UFR-BK14"
    ],
    "Door2": [
      "FB96-S1ND-68OT-TXOF",
      "DO6W-BZ8M-T1B9-L3UI",
      "M5YD-QV3I-QOO1-ZD2V",
      "R21Q-XQUL-QPHF-VVCN"
    ]
  }
}

Программа берет такие данные
{
  "Game": "Game1",
  "Pass": "I9IW-HSCL-90FM-2SJ8"
}

надо чтобы программа сверяла данные из файла ( его данные -  последний JSON документ), а после выводила, либо все окей,либо нет

А как сопоставляется "Door1" с "Game1"? Подсказка по разбору JSON: фигурные скобки - это словарь ключ:значение, квадратные скобки это список элементов итем1, итем2, ...

Я там просто упустил

Можете по подробнее?

Делаете классы под оба JSON. Первый JSON - это класс, внутри которого будет словарь, ключем которого является string, а значением массив строк. Для второго это просто класс с двумя строками. Получаете что-то такое: class Root { public Dictionary<string, string[]> Game { get; set;}  } ... class RequestRoot { public string Game { get; set; } public string Pass { get; set; }}. Далее десериализуете оба JSON, ну и далее var result = data.Game[request.Game].Contains(request.Pass);, получите true/false если в первом JSON есть указанный ключ. Пример грубый, есть огрехи, но суть думаю поняли.
